# Syncing UITableView with the Array

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView which is shown when the screen is loaded. The UITableView shows 7 items since the dishes array contains 7 items. I have button which adds one more item to the dishes array.

// adding just one more item to the array
                            self.dishes.append(contentsOf: filteredArray)

```
                        let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: self.dishes.count + 1, section: 0)
                        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
```

As soon as the new dish is added I get the following error:

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 10 into section 0, but there are only 9 rows in section 0 after the update'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Comment: I think, you need to call `tableView.reloadData`.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to avoid calling reloadData since when you call reloadData it looses the animation.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to see more of the code to understand what you're doing but I think you should be doing it more like this.

```
var dishes = [Dish]()

@IBAction func myButton(_ sender: Any) {
    dishes.append(Dish())
    collectionView.reloadData()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dishes.count
}
```

Comment: There is a lot of code but that is the part causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

The last row index will be self.dishes.count without adding 1.